# How can I call and active a function with using delegate in swift?

Tags: swift, controller, call, func

I created a sideMenu (like Twitter) in my HomeController. This controller has two function closeSideMenu() and openSideMenu() and both of them working. But When I try to close menu with didselectrow in MenuController (btw MenuController is a tableview controller) it doesn't work. I am using delegate, I created a protocol on the HomeController and code of MenuController is below. Please Can you help me ?

```
//this is in HomeController()
protocol ControlsDelegate {
func closeSideMenu()
}

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, HomePostCellDelegate {

var controlsMenu : ControlsDelegate?
...
...
...

//this is in MenuController()
extension MenuController: ControlsDelegate {
func closeSideMenu() {
}
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt IndexPath: IndexPath) {
print("clicked menu items..") // it is working
closeSideMenu()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating the Menu Controller, make sure you pass your HomeController as the delegate.

```
let menuController = MenuController()
menuController.delegate = self
self.present(menuController, animated: true) // Depends how you present the MenuController
```

Now inside your HomeController, you need to implement closeSideMenu()

```
func closeSideMenu() {
    //Implementation to hide Side Menu
}
```

Comment: yes I tried it but it is not working to me. Maybe I made some mistake somewhere but I don't know where is the mistake. I am the new about swift.